# Error while accessing a variable in jinja2

Tags: html, django, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 with Django framework.
I'm getting data into dictionary from views.py by the name 'content', then I have to print this Jinja snippet in a table.
Therefore, I need the length of each list in 'content', but the scope of the Jinja variable is not global .
Here is the Jinja snippet :

```
{%extends "webEs/index.html"%}
{%block content%}
{%set n = 0 -%}
{%for a in content%}
{%set n = {{a|length}} %}
{%endfor%}
{%for i in range(n)%}
<tr>
    {%for c in content%}

    <td>{{c[i]}}</td>

    {%endfor%}
</tr>
{%endfor%}

{%endblock%}
```

Please help me getting my requirement fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem, I'm posting it here so that it might help somebody.
This is how I solved it..

```
{%extends "webEs/index.html"%}    
     {%block content%}
          {%set n = [] %}
          {%for a in content%}
               {%do n.append(a|length)%}
          {%endfor%}
          {%for i in range(n[0])%}
              <tr>
              {%for c in content%}
                  <td>{{c[i]}}</td>
              {%endfor%}
              </tr>
          {%endfor%}
     {%endblock%}
```